# Caching big data

Tags: c#, .net, database, multithreading, caching

I have an application that monitors various systems in realtime. I got different reports with different fields depending on the monitored application. We are gathering data in 3 minute intervals. And these 3 minute intervals can be 120mb as raw json and 2-3mb as zipped or gzipped json. We are zipping then caching to the disk to avoid database requests by requesting those caches from disk, unzipping them and loading the json data to application. We are holding these caches for like 3 days to 30 days depending on the report type.

For years we have used disk caching. Zipping the 3 minute interval data and then saving it to disk. This led me to use a lot of locks and mutexes.

I know I'm not the only one with this kind of problem. My cache is big. My question is; Is there a better way to save this data and obtain it? Memory caching is not a solution for me because 30 days of data can't be on memory and I am not able to add memory to the server for this application. I need something else. Something better than disk and without the usage of locks.

P.S. : Application is also multi-threaded.

Comment: Please clarify following: (1)"We are zipping them to avoid database requests" (2) Relation between report and cache (3) Why "Memory caching is not a solution for me."

Comment: So you have 480 intervals a day at 120mb each (around 56GB of uncompressed data per day)? That's a lot of IO whether you hit a db, file, or cpu cycles to zip. I worked on a VoIP app and we compressed audio to mp3, used file system locally until it hit a certain threshold, then offloaded to a network share or FTP. So, I don't have a better answer than what you're already doing.

Comment: Yes, but like I said that 120mb json file can be zipped to 2mb. So 1 interval is 2 mb a whole day for 1 monitoring report is a gig.

Comment: I'm assuming the incoming stream of data once in, isn't modified later. Right? Do you have multiple writers or multiple/parallel data streams? How are readers interacting with system and using cache? And little more clarification on this statement "This led me to use a lot of locks and mutexes."

Comment: A lot of clients can connect to this application. If client requests an interval that is not cached yet. Application retrieves it from database and while doing this it creates the cache. As I said in my question application is also realtime. It retrieves every new interval from database and caches it. Since multiple clients want to see it realtime only the first client's request must be cached and others have to retrieve it from cache. So there goes the mutex. Mutex covers the disk writing sections in my application.

Comment: Have you considered another thread that dumps the cache to the disk? till then keep it in memory - and then your lock time is only the write time...

Comment: Have you considered some NoSQL storage engine? I am thinking at redis in particular... it is a in-memory, fast, key-value store with persistence, which should be a good fit for this kind of scenario. You can then defer most of the lock/consistency hassle to it.

Comment: Considering MongoDB with GridFS but I don't know if it is the best option for this operation. And about Redis, out platform is Windows and Redis doesn't have official driver for Windows plus c# library is new. I need more stable option.

Comment: @Xelom well, the "unofficial" port of redis is done by MS itself.. but I agree on that point, it is better to use Linux. As for the C# library, there is booksleeve http://code.google.com/p/booksleeve/ This site (SO) uses it :) so I bet it is pretty stable!

Comment: Thanks for the offer Lorenzo. I also checked Servicestack's Redis client. So lets say I'm using Redis. Is it holding all the cache in the memory? Is it dumping it to the disk at some point? I've got 3 servers all of them are VM's with 8gb ram. I think memory with redis with this amount of cache will be a big problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider a NoSQL storage engine. I am thinking at Redis in particular. Redis is a in-memory, fast, key-value store with persistence, which should be a good fit for this kind of scenario. You can then defer most of the lock/consistency hassle to it.

A problem with Redis is if you are really bound to a Windows env. There is an "unofficial" port of redis; the port is done by Microsoft itself.. but I admit that I would not be extremely confident in using it in production. 
As for a C# client/library, there is Booksleeve. This site (SO) uses it :) so I bet it is pretty stable!

Of course you will need to tailor Redis to your needs. Redis does offer persistence, and the persistence is configurable (see http://redis.io/topics/persistence). Also, it offers expiration of objects (http://redis.io/commands/expire), very handy for a cache-like mechanism, and the ability to build more complex, atomic commands starting from simpler ones.

I would use Redis to handle the in-memory cache, keeping all the (primary) keys in memory, with data both on disk and in-memory. The in-memory data associated with an volatile key. The primary key points to the in-memory key and to a file name; if the key it points at is invalid, you can re-load data and access it.

This is a complex solution, but it has two advantages:

- it should be vary fast
- it offloads some of the locks/etc burden to Redis
- should be easy to migrate from your solution to this one

Alternatively, Redis also offers a VM solution
http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-virtual-memory-story.html, but I do not know how stable it is, nor have I ever tried it.

Another alternative is to explore other NoSQL solutions; since you mentioned JSON data, I will look at MongoDB.

Finally, a crazy idea... are you on a 64-bit machine?
Have you considered "letting the OS handle it", with a really big page file and page-file-backed memory mapped files (or a standard file too)? Mind you, it might be a very BAD idea...! But it is something that maybe you could try out/research about?

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation. If I'm going to use Redis. How am I going to store my zip files in it? Like Zip files to binary or just the json string inside of it?

Comment: Keys and values are binary-safe strings (http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro), so you can even store the gzipped bytes inside a value.